# Dynamic routing depending on version number

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I am working on a web api on node.js using the Express3 framework and I would want my routing to look something like `/v0.1/function`.

Ideally, the routing should automatically load the specified version module by looking at the major and minor version number given in the url. My approach so far is:

```
app.use('/v:major.:minor', function(req) {
    return require('./v' + req.params.major + '.' +
        req.params.minor);
});
```

And in my `./v0.1/index.js`:

```
module.exports = function() {
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express();
    app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
        res.json({ success: true });
    });
    return app;
}();
```

If I call `/v0.1/test` now, it somehow does not match the route (404), but `app.get('/v:major.:minor', function(req, res) { /* ... */ });` is working just fine.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `app.all` (http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all)

This will make is accessible for all HTTP Verbs and still have the variable routing working.

I tested it and it seems to work.

Edited as per comment

```
app.all('/v:major.:minor/:endpoint', function(req, res, next) {
    var version_handler = require('./v' + req.params.major + '.' + req.params.minor);
    if (!req.params.endpoint in version_handler) // endpoint_isn't supported at this version, 404
    version_handler[req.params.endpoint](req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Could you provide your test? I can match the route and get the parameters with something like `app.all('/:param/*', function(req) {})`, but how do I then load my desired module and let that handle the routing from there on? I would need to be able to define further routes in the callback function.

Comment: Couldn't you just do `app.all('/v:major.:minor/endpoint', function(req, res, next) { require('./v' + req.params.major + '.' + req.params.minor).endpoint(req, res, next) })` for each endpoint you want?

Comment: The problem is that different versions might have different endpoints as new features are added or old dropped. I guess I could export an array of the endpoints and iterate over that - if what I want cannot be achieved otherwise, that's a solution I haven't thought about

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a more general handler. Then your module.exports is just an object where the key is the endpoint name, value is the handler for that endpoint. You can also do some fun changes in the endpoint variable to provide nested endpoints i.e. /v1.2/nested/endpoint

Comment: But how whould you handle additional parameters ? 
F.x. http://localhost/v1.0/articles and http://localhost/v1.0/article/3 with that single expression `/v:major.:minor/:endpoint`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `app.param()`. From the example in [express API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) :

```
app.param('id', /^\d+$/);

app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});
```

You must provide the regular expression for your parameter in URL, since major, minor both are non negative integers `/^\d+$/` should be it for you.

Comment: The half of the example you have given is taken from an approach to validating url parameters; I am having trouble with app.use not taking any. I need to load the `vX.Y` module dynamically depending on the url parameters and I don't see how this would help me doing that. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

### The Simplest way I found is chain a custom middleware:

#### Something like this:

```
app.use('/api/:version', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('The version name is : ', req.params.version)
    req.version=req.params.version; //use this inside api router
    next() // pass control to the next handler
},api);
```

**api** is your router object